# Appropriate verbs to describe future goals

Tags: verbs

When I want to describe my future goals such as short-term and long-term goals, which verb would be the most appropriate verb? TO BE or WOULD?

1- My short-term goal after graduation **would be** to relaunch my current business.

2- My short-term goal after graduation **is** to relaunch my current business.

3- My short-term goal after graduation **will be** to relaunch my current business.

Comment: Is it your goal now (for after graduation), or will it become your goal at a later time?

Comment: @Davo It is my goal right now that I will intend to achieve after graduation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relaunching your current business is something that will be happening in the future, but your goal (the *goal* itself) is something that currently exists, in the present. My goal *is*.

So although all 3 of your expressions sound natural, and you might hear a native speaker of English saying any of them,

> My short-term goal after graduation is to relaunch my current business.

sounds the most decisive and positive. The other two sound a little "wishy-washy" or weak, like: "my goal *would* be" (if I *had* a goal...?) or "my goal *will* be" (in the *future* - but who cares about that now...?).

Go with sentence #2.